# Gradle 6/Java 11 "module not found" error for poi and poi-ooxml but jars exist

Tags: java, gradle, module, dependencies, apache-poi

I'm having an issue that has been driving me crazy for days. I'm relatively new to the Java modular system but was managing to declare my dependencies correctly until I started to use poi.

Here is my build.gradle snippet (gradle v 6.4):

```
dependencies {

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.30'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre'

implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2'
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2'
```

}

Here are the poi jars correctly located in my gradle cache:

```
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.poi$ tree
.
├── poi
│   └── 4.1.2
│       ├── 964bf41cf68bce08e4ef6b2279b559fdf8d454f4
│       │   └── poi-4.1.2.jar
│       ├── 9ce4c76815903772b25324d8419df2d3fe227f4d
│       │   └── poi-4.1.2.pom
│       └── ac5af3832ebaef94562a39591a000338bbae0e4b
│           └── poi-4.1.2-sources.jar
├── poi-ooxml
│   └── 4.1.2
│       ├── 712cc02d5bbe729d2485a1579f3d8dfc47e25b51
│       │   └── poi-ooxml-4.1.2-sources.jar
│       ├── 87d9a22aa9a7dd26e80c360e709f7ee02e32ab3b
│       │   └── poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar
│       └── ccbcde71e4f0fdfa80e1007dd1babfc9828c629e
│           └── poi-ooxml-4.1.2.pom
```

Here is my module-info.java:

```
module template {
    requires spring.core;
    requires poi;
    requires poi.ooxml;
}
```

Here is the error I get on running gradle clean build:

```
error: module not found: poi
    requires poi;
             ^
```

Things I have tried:

1. Deleting my gradle cache and doing a complete --refresh-dependencies build
2. Finding all the poi and poi-ooxml subdependencies and adding to the build.gradle
3. Using "api" instead of "implementation" for poi and poi-ooxml in the build.gradle

I am at my wits end on this -working on my day off! - and could really appreciate some input.

Comment: Update - a temporary fix has been for me to go into each jar file and add the "Automatic-Module-Name" attribute, setting it explicitly to the values in the module-info.java. However the java ModuleFinder should have done that automatically.

Comment: Java Modules are not good in all situations, and generally don't work well with modules that need backwards compatibility with older Java versions. Maybe just switch to using classpath instead?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But java should be creating an automatic module from the POI jars in the same way as it has with all the other pre-java9 jars that I am using, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in my comment above, I only got this to work by going into the poi library jar and adding the following to MANIFEST.MF:

```
Automatic-Module-Name: poi
```

The automatic module should have been created by java without this (it just generates the module name from the jar name) but wasn't until I added this. However automatic modules were created correctly with other libraries so can't quite see what makes this different.

This is not a long term solution but thought I'd post here in case it helps anyone.